# Evaluation of all solutions such that $~ y(x)>0 ~$ for $~ x>0 ~$where $~y(x)~$ is a general solution of $2$nd order linear nonhomogeneous DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, systems-of-equations

The essential problem statement is shown far below this post with bold italic font.

$$ \text{Evalution of solution}~  y(x) ~ \text{of}~ y''+\sqrt{5}y'-y+2=0   $$
**My works**

$$\begin{align}
  y''+\sqrt{5}y'-y+2&=0\\
  \iff  \underbrace{\color{fuchsia}{y''+\sqrt{5}y'-y=-2}}_{\text{ODE which originally given} }   \\
  \underbrace{y''+\sqrt{5}y'-y=0}_{\text{Homogeneous DE} }\\
  t^2+\sqrt5t-1&=0\\
  t&={-\sqrt5\pm\sqrt{5+4} \over 2 }\\&= {-\sqrt5\pm3 \over  2}\\
  C_1,C_2&:= \text{arbitrary constants} \\
  y&=\underbrace{C_1 \exp\left(\left( {-\sqrt5-3 \over  2}\right) x\right)+    C_2 \exp\left(\left( {-\sqrt5+3 \over  2}\right) x\right)}_{\text{General soln for the homogeneous DE} } \\
  \\ A&:= \text{trial particular soln for the pink DE}\\
  \\y&=A\\
  y''=y'&=0~\text{since}~A~ \text{is a constant.} 
  \\ \left(y''+\sqrt5y'-y \right) \Bigg|_{y=A} &=-2\Bigg|_{y=A}\\\iff-A&=-2\\\therefore \underbrace{A=2}_{\text{particular soln for the pink DE} } 
\end{align}$$

$$\therefore \underbrace{y(x)=C_1 \exp\left(\left( {-\sqrt5-3 \over  2}\right) x\right)+    C_2 \exp\left(\left( {-\sqrt5+3 \over  2}\right) x\right)+2}_{\text{General soln for the pink DE} }  $$
**Ended my works**

***Evaluate all solutions such that $~ y(x)>0 ~$ for $~ x>0 ~$***

At least it can be easiely said that for  $~C_1,C_2\geq0~$, the given condition is satisfied. But I've been struggling to assess about the rest ranges. I've thought the following.

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt5&\approx2.236\\
\alpha:&= {-\sqrt5-3 \over 2 }\in\mathbb{R}_{<0}\\
\alpha'&:=-\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\\
\beta:&= {-\sqrt5+3 \over 2 }\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\\
0&< \underbrace{C_1 \exp\left(\alpha x \right)+ C_2 \exp\left(\beta x \right)+2}_{y(x)}  \\
0&< C_1e^{\alpha x}+C_2 e^{\beta x}+2\\
0&< C_1e^{-\alpha' x}+C_2 e^{\beta x}+2\\
0&< {C_1 \over e^{\alpha'x} }  +C_2 e^{\beta x}+2\\
0&< {C_1 \over e^{\alpha'x} }  + {C_2 e^{\beta x} e^{\alpha'x}\over e^{\alpha'x} } +2\times {e^{\alpha'x} \over e^{\alpha'x} } \\
0&< {C_1+C_2e^{(\alpha'+\beta)x} +2e^{\alpha'x}\over e^{\alpha'x} }
\end{align}$$

$$ \underbrace{\color{blue}{0<C_1+C_2e^{(\alpha'+\beta)x} +2e^{\alpha'x}} 　}_{\text{I've been stucked from here} }  $$

Which website(s) is/are helpful or can I evaluate it with short calculation(s)?

I need your help.

Comment: Made corrections of e.g. miss-calculations.

Comment: You should be able to see why $C_2<0$ is impossible, and why $C_1+C_2>0$ should be a good idea. There might be further restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, a sufficient condition is $C_1,C_2\ge0$ and a necessary condition is $C_2\ge0.$

In the remaining case$$C_2\ge0,C_1<0,$$we have$$\forall x\in\mathbb R\quad y'(x)>0$$hence the condition for $y(x)$ to be $>0$ whenever $x>0$ is $y(0)\ge0,$ i.e. $C_1+C_2+2\ge0.$

Alltogether, the solutions $y$ of your ODE such that $\forall x\in\mathbb R_+^*\quad y(x)>0$ are those for which
$$C_2\ge0\quad\text{and}\quad C_1\ge-C_2-2.$$

Comment: I can't understand why $C_2 \geq0$ is a necessary condition in the first place...

Comment: Else, $\lim y$ at $+\infty$ would be $-\infty.$

Comment: I've got the following from your that advice.
$$\begin{align}
y(x)&= \underbrace{C_1 e^{\alpha x}}_{\alpha<0}  +C_2  \underbrace{e^{\beta x}}_{\beta>0}  +2\\
&= {{C_1 \over \underbrace{e^{\alpha'x}}_{\alpha'>0}  }+C_2 e^{\beta x}+2}\\
\lim_{ x \to +\infty}y(x)&= \lim_{ x \to +\infty} \left({C_1 \over {e^{\alpha'x}} }+C_2 e^{\beta x}+2 \right)>0
\\
\lim_{ x \to +\infty}y(x)&= \lim_{ x \to +\infty} \left(C_2 e^{\beta x} \right)+2>0\\\therefore~& C_2 ~\text{can't be negative to satisfy }~y(x)>0~ \text{for}~x>0  
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, or for short; for all $C_2\ne0$, since $\beta>0>\alpha,$ $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}y(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(C_2e^{\beta x}\right)=C_2\times(+\infty),$$hence this limit is $-\infty$ if $C_2<0.$

Comment: I see. BTW I realized that $~C_1~$ can be any real number before a value of $~C_2~$ is determined, while as $~C_2~$ is firstly determined then the range of $~C_1~$ is strictly constrained.

Comment: Yes, "$C_2\ge0\quad\text{and}\quad C_1\ge-C_2-2$" 